# Laravel generate tags, how to?

Tags: laravel

I want to achieve the following:

I have a project `Talbe`, where I can save two things:

1. Multiple Photos of the project
2. Filter/Tags?

- I want to make a form where I can create multiple uploads of photos (later on, I will show it in the view)
- I want that I can pass 3 things. I already created 3 classes, which separates those tags with color. So if the Project has, let say, "html" in it, it would be displayed as green and so on.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

There are too many ways to that and one of them is:

1. Create 2 migrations with foreign keys (one for photos and another one for tags)
2. Create an HTML form to add tags and photos and validate the form request properly (ex. for photos: `['required'|'mimes:jpg,png']`)
3. for adding color you can use bootstrap to etc.